# Discord Auth redirect on mobile to open app not browser?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, discord

I've a simple URL in my discord bot and my website

```
https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${settings.discord.clientId}&redirect_uri=${settings.discord.redirect}&response_type=code&scope=identify
```

Now my redirect URL points to my server.

Now when I use the above code, it works fine if I'm using a browser,
but now for mobile users, It also works fine, but it asks them to login to discord on their browser (chrome/safari).

**Now is it possible for the redirect URL to open `discord app` if the user on mobile?**